# How to implement custom tabs titles animation and position

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, android-animation

I have seen a great design in one app.
There is custom tabs representation and animation.
If the tabs doesn't has next(the last tab) there are only two tabs on the screen current at the center and adjacent.
And there is custom animation when switchng between tabs.
How to implement similiar tabs view and custom animation.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I will be grateful everyone for help.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at this beautiful library: https://github.com/jpardogo/PagerSlidingTabStrip. It's exactly the same what you want I think. If you want to add some beatiful transition animations between the fragments, you can check this: https://github.com/jfeinstein10/JazzyViewPager